# vimの公式ドキュメントにおけるパターンと検索コマンドで改行(\n)の部分に理解できない記述があります。

Tags: vim

vimの公式ドキュメントにおけるパターンと検索コマンドで改行(\n)の部分に以下の記述があります。
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern-atoms

```
\n  matches an end-of-line              */\n*
    When matching in a string instead of buffer text a literal newline
    character is matched.
```

この `When matching in a string instead of buffer text a literal newline character is matched.` の部分の意味がわかりません。どのような場合に検知できるのでしょうか?

以下の実験をしました。
ファイルに以下の記述をし、vimのコマンドラインに`/\n`と入力しましたが、全ての場合でリテラルの改行文字とマッチすることはありませんでした。

```
"\n"
'\n'
\n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim において、正規表現は `/` による検索の他に Vim script 内での正規表現マッチに利用されます。
`matching in a string instead of buffer text` は、`/` によるバッファテキストの検索ではなくこの Vim script 内での使用のことを指します。

```
let string = "foo\nbar"  " 改行を含む文字列
echo string =~# '\n'     " 文字列が改行を含んでいるかどうかを =~# 演算子を使って正規表現マッチ
```